# Everything.exe asks me constantly for Admin password upon start

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I (Win7, 64) installed Everything.exe from voidtool.com.

It is started as service and now if I start Everything.exe (v.1.4.0.713b (x64)) as a normal user it should accept me, but it asks constantly for the admin password and then it runs by the admin.

This is quite inconvenient not only because of the wrong default paths but I have to type again and again the admin password.

1. I checked everything I found (Windows start option, Everything's options, ...) to make sure that the option "Run program as Administrator" in the Compatibility tab and elsewhere is unchecked!
2. Under the General-Tab of the properties of Everything.exe it is NOT written "Security:This file came from another computer and might be blocked".
3. I enabled me as a user with the same rights as the admin. But I as a user can't start it. Everything requests admin password.

Is there a way to start this program just as user without pulling down UAC to zero?

Where else can I search?

Comment: It sounds like the program requires Administrator permission to run.  The simple solution is change the user group, your user, is a member of.  Of course it is not recomended to always use an elevated user for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Have you tried asking support? https://voidtools.com/contact/

Comment: Yes I asked them, but this problem was already posted 1 year ago without any answer - despite that I asked there again - nothing helpful so far.

Comment: I posted there https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1677&p=15277#p15277 at the bottom that it might be a mismatch of options as the started Everything-Service seems to be ignored and is running 3 times if I want to use it :(

Answer (score 0):

This a problem I solved a while ago. Create a scheduled task.

1. Disable the everything start on boot-up option
2. Create a scheduled task with the following options:

   - Run When used is logged on
   - Run With Highest Privileges setting.
   - Trigger: At Logon
   - Action: Start a program Program/Script:`"C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe"` Add arguments: `-startup`

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, despite Everything's option "Run as Administrator" was disabled  %APPDATA%\Everything\Everything.ini still had the entry:  run_as_admin=1.

After correcting this manually it works as expected - without asking for the Admin.-Pwd upon start!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the everything.exe program. (C:\Program Files\Everything most likely)
2. display properties
3. on compatibility page there is "Run as administrator" checkbox
   Enjoy!

Comment: This issue has been fixed, if you install it as service, it'll work superb (no admin ever requested.)